# How do I replace part of a string?

Tags: c#, .net, string

Supposed I have the following strings:

```
string str1 = "<tag tsdfg> some other random text";
string str2 = "<tag sdfgsdfgfsdg> some other random text";
string str3 = "<tag 1564> some other random text";
```

i would like to change those strings to

```
"<tag> some other random text"
```

Comment: `str1 = str2 = str3 = "<tag>"` ? :)

Comment: hmm i gave a bad example :p

Comment: @SonerGönül actually `str1 = str2 = str3 = "<tag> some other random text"` for correctness! :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
str1 = Regex.Replace(str1, @"\<tag.*?\>", "<tag>");
```

Fiddle:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/LdokRn

Comment: I think you need `"\<tag.*?\>"` to stop regex being greeedy. Otherwise this is fine. +1

Comment: You are right, in the OPs case it would not be needed, but as a general solution, yes. Will edit

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to replace all the arbitrary text inside the tag

```
Regex.Replace("<tag tsdfg> some random text", @"<(.*)?\s+(.*)?>", "<$1>");
```

This will effectively replace any text, after whitespace, at the end of any tag.

[Try it out](https://ideone.com/J7QLtC)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yeah I realised the regex was invalid after I posted the answer, I have updated with one that will replace everything inside the tag after whitespace.

Comment: Still that's not correct. please test yourself. Op asks for `<tag> some other random text` but your answer gives `some other random text`

Comment: The OP question is not edited (you can see this in Stack Overflow). A regex would be the way to go IMO, but your sample code (both the regex, the input, and the replacement) are just wrong as an answer to the question

Comment: @Jcl yeah I get that and I am fixing, but the question has changed when it was originally posted, there was no mention of "some other random text" in the original post (remember there is a grace period  so you can edit questions without it been deemed "edited").

Comment: I see, my bad. Sorry then! Will remove my downvote when you edit :-)

Comment: @Jcl I have updated the answer, I unfortunately I couldn't get the *perfect* approach which incorporated non-capturing groups to work exactly but the above would suffice, and is a more flexible approach than the accepted answer. Criticism/improvements welcome.

Comment: @James I have removed my downvote. I think what you'd want would be more in the line of: `Regex.Replace(str1, @"<(.*)?\s+(.*)?>", "<$1>");` as a general solution (probably not bug-free, haven't really checked).

Comment: @jcl agreed, completely forgot that you can use the groups as part of the replace :) (a bit rusty with Regex, not used it in a while...) Updated.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
str1.Replace((str1.Substring(str1.IndexOf("<"), str1.IndexOf(">"))), "<tag>");
```

Answer (score 1):

If after `<tag` there will always  be a **white-space** ,then you can use `Split()` this way:

```
string str1 = "<tag tsdfg> some other random text";
string values = str1.Split(' ')[0]+">";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
str1="<tag>" + str1.Remove(0, str1.IndexOf(">") + 1);
```

it removes from index 0 to >+1 and then add it to "tag"

Comment: That does not achieve the requirement

Comment: He is trying to change it to remove the "tsdfg" inside the tag.

Comment: @JustinHarvey added tsdfg accidently, you could comment it before downvote, don't you think it would be better? is it ok now?

Comment: there is no need to get funny, I was just trying to point out the problem in your answer.  I think that edit is really for improving answers rather than fixing the fact they are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way:

```
string str = "<tag tsdfg> some other random text";

string newStr = new string(str.TakeWhile(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
                              .Concat(str.SkipWhile(c => c != '>'))
                              .ToArray());

Console.WriteLine(newStr);  //  "<tag> some other random text"
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's make it at least once unlike the other solutions not about removing or replacing but extracting ;-]

```
string str1 = "<tag tsdfg> some other random text";

Match match = Regex.Match(str1, @"\<(tag).+?\>(.+)");
string result = String.Format("<{0}>{1}", match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[2].Value);
Console.WriteLine(result );
```